# How to start ediff-ing a file that has git conflict markers in it?

Tags: git, ediff, prelude

Following an attempted git merge on the commandline, my file now has standard conflict markers in it which emacs has helpfully reloaded (reverted?) in the buffer.

How do I start some kind of merging mode to resolve the conflict? Can I get seperate buffers showing left/right/merged versions of the file like when I ediff-files?

(emacs-prelude v24.4 on a Mac)

Comment: All three of these look good.  Thank you! I will make a conflicted file, try each answer, and report back about my experience.

Answer (score 17):

If you use [magit](https://github.com/magit/magit), you can press <kbd>e</kbd> at the unmerged file in magit status buffer (started by pressing <kbd>M-x</kbd>`magit-status`<kbd>RET</kbd>) to start ediff session for resolving the conflicts

Answer (score 12):

You can use the minor mode `smerge-mode` to move between conflicts and resolve them. You can open ediff to resolve conflicts with `C-c ^ E` while in smerge mode.

Answer (score 11):

<kbd>M-x</kbd> `vc-resolve-conflicts` <kbd>RET</kbd>

I bind it to <kbd>C-x</kbd><kbd>v</kbd><kbd><</kbd>