# Enable smerge-mode for already opened file

Tags: magit, emacsclient, git

`smerge-mode` doesn't always get enabled for git merge conflicts. I think this happens when I visit a file using `emacsclient` which is already opened in a buffer. Something (maybe magit?) is causing the file to be auto-reverted from the filesystem, so the conflict markers appear, but unfortunately the presence of the conflict markers do not cause `smerge-mode` to be activated. How can I make `smerge-mode` be activated as soon as conflict markers appear in the file, regardless of whether it's freshly opened or just reverted?

Answer (score 6):

This is what I have in my init file :

```
(defun smerge-try-smerge ()
  (save-excursion
    (goto-char (point-min))
    (when (re-search-forward "^<<<<<<< " nil t)
      (require 'smerge-mode)
      (smerge-mode 1))))
(add-hook 'find-file-hook 'smerge-try-smerge t)
(add-hook 'after-revert-hook 'smerge-try-smerge t)
```

The defun is suggested in smerge documentation, as well as the first hook. The second hook I can't remember if I saw it somewhere or just thought it was good, but all in all it seems that it Works For Me©.